# Android: Listening for barcode scanner button being pressed

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, motorola-droid

I have a Motorola TC55, that is equipped with a hardware barcode scanner.  What i'd like to do is listen for that button being pressed in my app.  I've googled and looked on SO without any luck.  Can someone point me to a resource, or suggest how i can get started?

Comment: You would have to ask Motorola, or write yourself a test activity that overrides methods like `onKeyDown()` to see if they get triggered by this button press. If they do, then you will have information, like the `KeyEvent`, to know how to react to it.

Comment: Great! thank you for the pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Motorola TC55 the hardware scan button is mapped to the key "BUTTON_L1" by default so this is what you'd listen for like below.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_L1 {
    //Do something scanner was pressed.
  }
}
```

You can see the key it is mapped to through Settings->Programmable Keys